# RabbitMQ Generic server rabbit_connection_tracking terminating

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, erlang

I have RabbitMQ cluster running on Kubernetes.

I found this error in one of RabbitMQ pods:

```
[error] <0.13899.4> ** Generic server rabbit_connection_tracking terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',{connection_closed,[{name,<<"10.182.60.4:52930 -> 10.182.60.93:5672">>},{pid,<0.13926.4>},{node,'rabbit@10.182.60.93'},{client_properties,[]}]}}
** When Server state == nostate
** Reason for termination ==
** {{aborted,{no_exists,['tracked_connection_on_node_rabbit@10.182.60.93',{'rabbit@10.182.60.93',<<"10.182.60.4:52930 -> 10.182.60.93:5672">>}]}},[{mnesia,abort,1,[{file,"mnesia.erl"},{line,355}]},{rabbit_connection_tracking,unregister_connection,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_connection_tracking.erl"},{line,282}]},{rabbit_connection_tracking,handle_cast,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_connection_tracking.erl"},{line,101}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,637}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,711}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}
```

It's occurs in this pod only.

> **Where:**
>
> Kubernetes nodes count: 2
>
> Rabbitmq pods count: 3
>
> 10.182.60.4: is one of K8s nodes
>
> 10.182.60.93: is the RabitMQ pods that has the error.

the error doesn't affect the flow of messages. but I can't understand what does it mean!
and why it occurs in this pod only!

Comment: Please provide output of `kubectl describe node | grep "Allocated resources:" -A 8` and `kubectl describe pod <affectedPod>`